# Saving a json file on Heroku

Tags: ruby, json, heroku

I have a simple sinatra app on Heroku which fetches some json data and is then fetched again and rewritten every 10 minutes, what would be the easiest way to save the json data?

Should I use S3 or mongodb or is there a simpler option?

Comment: A file? Or is that not an option?

Comment: Yeah, Linuxios is write easiest to write to is the current file system.

Comment: I believe the file system is read-only on Heroku.  So saving to file is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think writing into a database (mongodb or other) would be your best bet. It's simplest to set up on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest route is to save your json using Heroku's free 5mb [memcached plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache) (use the dalli gem),

[This link](http://www.informedgeek.com/2011/07/using-dalli-client-with-heroku-memcache-plugin-in-sinatra/) describes setting up a sinatra app with memcache

Again, I think that is going to be your least complicated approach.

Comment: I found it easier just using mongodb, I couldn't quite figure out how to use the memcache plugin