# how to store JSON files on heroku (discord bot)

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I am programming a bot on discord and I wish I could save the JSON file data on heroku. When I start the bot from my pc the JSON files work and do their job while if I start it from heroku they are restored at every restart.

I understood that I should have hosted the data in an area related to heroku but how could I do it? What are the possible solutions to have JSON files that remain static even when hosting the bot on heroku?

(If possible, could you send useful videos? I'm new and I'd like to learn better)

N.B I would like solutions with JSON not with other archives.

Comment: "What are the possible solutions to have JSON files that remain static even when hosting the bot on heroku?" If you intend to modify those files you can't host them on Heroku. They'll get reset to whatever state they were when you deployed frequently. Use S3 or Azure Blob storage or, better yet, use a real database. This is well covered in countless posts here and in the official documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving a json file on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316830/saving-a-json-file-on-heroku)

Comment: no ... then is there any alternative host that allows to modify JSON?

Comment: Sure, lots of other hosts do. But not ones with Heroku's model, which is designed for easy scaling by making nodes disposable and interchangeable.

Comment: what kind of host do you recommend? sorry for these questions but currently I would like something that will allow you to modify JSON and that even in case of sudden reboots do not get lost and not being very practical at the host level I find myself in difficulty

Comment: I recommend one that does what Heroku does. There are solid technical reasons that it operates the way it does. JSON files saved to the local filesystem are rarely a good idea. Use a real database.

Comment: but I should redo all the codes and we are in the summer :(

Comment: I don't know what you want from me: your application _is currently incompatible with Heroku_. Either move to another host of your choosing or modify your application so it doesn't persist data by writing to a locally-stored JSON file.

Comment: do you know any suitable alternative host?

Comment: Just pick one. Any VPS should do.